# Trying to install Glib via cpanm, cc access denied

Tags: perl, glib, access-denied, cc

I'm trying to install the Glib module via cpanm. I have all the prereqs, but during the "building and testing" stage, the installation fails. I checked the build log, and it looks like my access was denied when the app called "cc Glib.c". I have MinGw compiler, and am the admin for my computer. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: This the actual error message from the last four lines of the build log.

[ CC Glib.c ]

Access is denied.

dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Glib.o'

-> FAIL Installing Glib failed. See .cpanm\build.log for details.

Here is the full log:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.5015 on perl 5.014002 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
Work directory is /.cpanm/work/1342897626.5500
You have make C:\Perl\c\bin\dmake.exe
You have LWP 6.03
You have C:\Eclipse\bin\tar.exe, C:\Eclipse\bin\gzip.exe and C:\Eclipse\bin\bzip2.exe
Searching Glib on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Glib
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/X/XA/XAOC/Glib-1.261.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Glib-1.261.tar.gz
Entering Glib-1.261
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Configuring Glib-1.261
Running Makefile.PL
Including generated API documentation...
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Glib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.62)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Depends 0.300 ... Yes (0.304)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::PkgConfig 1.00 ... Yes (1.13)
Building and testing Glib-1.261
cp lib/Glib/GenPod.pm blib\lib/Glib/GenPod.pm
cp build/IFiles.pm blib\arch/Glib/Install/Files.pm
cp C:\.cpanm\work\1342897626.5500\Glib-1.261\typemap blib\arch/Glib/Install/typemap
cp lib/Glib.pm blib\lib/Glib.pm
cp gperl.h blib\arch/Glib/Install/gperl.h
cp lib/Glib/Object/Subclass.pm blib\lib/Glib/Object/Subclass.pm
cp devel.pod blib\lib/Glib/devel.pod
cp gperl_marshal.h blib\arch/Glib/Install/gperl_marshal.h
cp lib/Glib/MakeHelper.pm blib\lib/Glib/MakeHelper.pm
cp lib/Glib/ParseXSDoc.pm blib\lib/Glib/ParseXSDoc.pm
cp lib/Glib/CodeGen.pm blib\lib/Glib/CodeGen.pm
cp doctypes blib\arch/Glib/Install/doctypes
[ XS Glib.xs ]
[ CC Glib.c ]
Access is denied.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Glib.o'
-> FAIL Installing Glib failed. See \.cpanm\build.log for details.
```

Comment: Posting some relevant error messages/console output may help folks answering your question. I would recommend pastebin if it's too long/verbose

Comment: Those are the last four lines. I wasn't sure if everything else was relevant. I just put in a link to pastebin that contains the full log, hope that it helps. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do you actually have a C compiler?

Comment: IMO, you should check your PATH settings to the compiler

Comment: yeah, that was actually the first thing I did, and it looked fine. I've installed a lot of modules this way before, which is why the error is so odd.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Wow, you know what, I just checked the bin that my PATH led to, and I don't have a cc.exe. I'm guessing that that would be the C compiler?